# How do I reshape a 3D list to 1D list?

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a code where I am getting a 3 dimensional list, I am trying to convert it to 1 dimensional.

Comment: `np.ravel(input_list).tolist()`?

Comment: @Divakar there must be a dupe of this

Comment: You have a list of list of lists or a ndarray with three axes? Better show the code to make it clear.

Comment: Flattening a python list: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/812912 flattening a numpy ndarray: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are two simple solutions to the problem:

```
originl_list = [[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]], [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]]
final_list = []

def method1():
    for i in lst1:
        for j in i:
            for k in j:
                final_list.append(k)

    print(final_list)


def method2():
    [final_list.append(k) for i in originl_list for k in i for j in k]

    print(final_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.